# Get the least difference of numeric vector

Tags: r

How to get the least difference present between two numbers in a numeric vector in R. For e.g:

```
foo<- c(1,2,2.5,3,4)
```

The least difference for the above vector is 0.5 (2.5-2).

Currently, I use the following code to achieve my objective:

```
> sapply(1:length(foo), function (x)(foo[-x] - foo[x]))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1.0 -1.0 -1.5 -2.0 -3.0
[2,]  1.5  0.5 -0.5 -1.0 -2.0
[3,]  2.0  1.0  0.5 -0.5 -1.5
[4,]  3.0  2.0  1.5  1.0 -1.0
> min(abs(sapply(1:length(foo), function (x)(foo[-x] - foo[x]))))
[1] 0.5
```

Are there any readily available packages which does the same with a single command or any more efficient ways of doing the same?

Comment: you can try `min(diff(foo))`

Comment: This will fail when when it is unsorted. E.g. `foo <- c(2.5,5,3,1)`

Comment: Obviously you have to `sort` if you want your result in that way. I thought you wanted min difference between each element as is.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Works that way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
foo<- c(1,2,2.5,4,3)
min(diff(sort(foo)), na.rm=TRUE) #sort the data in ascending order then take the differences
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min` of `diff`. The `diff` provides difference between consecutive element, with  default argument `lag=1`. Then finally take `min` of the same.

```
min(diff(foo))
#[1] 0.5
```